# Where to place javascript functions in Meteor applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In Meteor we normally attach javascript functions to Templates. Where do we place standard javascript functions?

For instance, in one of my apps I have a **UserInfo.js** file which has a bunch of javascript functions for handling users logging in and getting user information.

Below are two of my functions in **UserInfo.js**

File is located in the *client/scripts* folder:

```
isAdminById = function(userId) {
  var user;
  user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
  return user && isAdmin(user);
};

isAdmin = function(user) {
  if (!user || typeof user === 'undefined') {
    return false;
  } else {
    return !!user.isAdmin;
  }
};
```

When I run the app and call isAdmin() from the browser console it says:

`ReferenceError: isAdmin is not defined`

### ---- Edit ----

It seems the problem was fixed temporarily when I placed the javascript file under the **client/compatibility** folder but now the issue has resurfaced. The only thing I remember changing was calling `>> Meteor Reset`

#### More Info:

I think the issue arises when I use coffeescript. When I convert my coffeescript files to js files everything seems to work.

Comment: Everything you wrote works fine in v0.6.5.1. What meteor version are you running?

Comment: You're maybe calling your function before the browser has loaded it. Make sure that every call to `isAdmin` lies within a function that's executed after the start up.

Comment: I'm running version v0.6.5.1. I attempted to call isAdmin from the Firebug console after the application loaded and was running.

Comment: Hi @FreeLancer, if you upload a repro to github, it will be a lot easier for others to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare coffeescript variables as global with `@`:

```
@isAdmin = user -> ...
```

This is due to how Meteor variable shadowing works in connection with coffeescript automatic variable declaration.

Coffeescript by default does the "smart" variable declaration by itself - basically by placing `var variableName` in the first place in javascript where the variable is visible. In your case, this causes `isAdmin` to be declared by `var` in js, and therefore it's scoped to the file.

Using `@` char supersedes this default behavior by binding the variable to `this`, `global` or `window` object instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, it's probably a [load order](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp) problem.

Comment: My javascript file is just a list of many methods and I have it placed inside the **client/scripts** folder which should load it properly correct?

Comment: Ok, so after digging deeper into the link you mentioned it seems placing the javascript file in the **client/compatibility** folder solved it:

`Some JavaScript libraries only work when placed in the client/compatibility subdirectory. Files in this directory are executed without being wrapped in a new variable scope. This means that each top-level var defines a global variable. In addition, these files are executed before other client-side JavaScript files.`